# How to have partially italicized columns in pdf output?

Tags: pdf, kable, kableextra

This question is related to [Creating a data frame that produces partially italicized cells with pkg:sjPlot functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63274044/creating-a-data-frame-that-produces-partially-italicized-cells-with-pkgsjplot-f)

I'd like to have partially italicized cells in a `kable`. I have tried

```
library(tidyverse); library(kableExtra)

sum_dat_final2 <- list(Site = c("Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki"), 
                   Coral_taxon = expression( italic(Montipora)~ spp., 
                                             italic(Pocillopora)~spp., 
                                             italic(Porites)~spp., 
                                             italic(Montipora)~ spp.,  
                                             italic(Pocillopora)~spp.,  
                                             italic(Porites)~spp.))

sum_dat_final2 %>%
  as.data.frame()%>%
  kbl(longtable = F, "latex")
```

and got this error `Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) :  cannot coerce class ‘"expression"’ to a data.frame`

Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may italicize specific parts by adding `$`. In this sense, you need to set `escape = F` on your `kbl` function.

````
```{r}
library(tidyverse); library(kableExtra)

sum_dat_final2 <- list(Site = c("Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki"), 
                   "Coral_taxon" = c("$Montipora$$~$ spp.",
                                   "$Pocillopora$$~$spp.",
                                   "$Porites$$~$spp.",
                                   "$Montipora$$~$ spp.",
                                   "$Pocillopora$$~$spp.",
                                   "$Porites$$~$spp."))

sum_dat_final2 %>%
  as.data.frame()%>%
  kbl(longtable = F, "latex", 
      escape = F,
      col.names = c("Site", "Coral taxonomie"))
```
````

--output

[image]